# bitbake package-index not creating repomd.xml

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I followed the section on [runtime package management](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/packages.html#using-runtime-package-management) from the yocto manual.
I set `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"` and added `package-management` to `IMAGE_FEATURES`. In my image I find `dnf` being installed.

After configuration of the repository endpoints `dnf` exits with `Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried.`
And in fact, after building my image I ran `bitbake package-index` and was expecting to find a file `repomd.xml` next to the numerous `rpm`s that were produced in the build tmp directory `build/tmp-orange-pi-zero/deploy/rpm/orange_pi_zero` but it is not there.

Did I miss a configuration step that hinders from producing the `repomd.xml` file? I couldn't find issues in the logs.